# Offline Login Unity 3D and PHP Laravel

Tags: c#, php, laravel, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project combining `Unity3D` and `PHP` `Laravel` framework for user authentication. At this time the project lets the user register and login but I need to make offline login persistent and I can't figure out how to make that.

I'm using passport in `Laravel`.

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

When the user is offline you need to cache the data locally on users device. Once the user is back online your application should detect that and synchronize the data with your server.

You should be aware of data conflicts and versioning.